# Can I use res.send() on a trycatch block?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using a node route and I use a `trycatch` block but Node.js is not having it. When there is an error with the code and it goes to the catch, it fails.

```
try {
 ... 
 res.send({ message: 'All good nothing wrong with the code above' })
} catch {
 res.status(500).send({ message: 'There is an error I want to send to the front end' })
}
```

Node clearly is not happy about this, I know I cannot send `res.send()`twice but it is on a `trycatch` block. How do I send an error message back the front end if something fails?

Node complains with on the catch block:

```
'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'
```

---

UPDATE

I fixed it by sending the error object with throw to the catch block and not to use `res.send()` on the try catch for any conditional other than just once

Comment: `Node clearly is not happy about this` - how?If error is not caught, then `All good nothing wrong with the code above` should be sent (of course if something else was not sent before`. If error is caught, you'll get the second one

Comment: With this: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: @MichałSkorzec if I put `res.end()` on the catch block it does not crash

Comment: You can use [`res.headersSent`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_headerssent) to check… well… if headers are sent.

Comment: The [Express.js Error Handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) documentation is also very helpful to read. It provides solutions using middleware.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to terminate the execution flow of the function when you want to send something and not do anything else afterwards.

```
res.send('All ok');
console.log('Response sent');
return;

or

return res.send('All ok');


try {
   throw Error('Oops')
   return res.send('OK')
} catch(error) {
   return res.send('Not OK: ' + error.message)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not on a `trycatch`

Comment: You still can return inside of `try{ return res.send(...) }` and `catch(err){ return res.send(...) }`

Comment: I have tried all combinations and I always get a crash, only way to avoid the crash is by doing `res.end()` but then I am not sending anything.

Comment: Are there any middlewares? How does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: There's a lot more code, something else might be conflicting then

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two times `res.send` so add `return`.

```
try {
 ... 
} catch {
   res.status(500).send({ message: 'There is an error I want to send to the front end' })
   return;
}
res.send({ message: 'All good nothing wrong with the code above' })
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error, even with the `return` on the catch